# Return file download from storage in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to be able to retrieve a file from storage in my controller.

```
public function getFile($fileID) {
    $file = CommUploads::where('id', $fileID)->first();

    if (Auth::user()->id == $file->user_id || Auth::user()->id == $file->artist_id) {
        $fileGet = Storage::get($file->file_path);
        return $fileGet;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm able to get the path correctly, however, all that comes out is gibberish, as if you're looking at an image without the extension.

Ideally I'd like this to work as a "save as" sort of thing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a [file download response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-downloads).

```
public function getFile($fileID) {
    $file = CommUploads::where('id', $fileID)->first();

    if (Auth::user()->id == $file->user_id || Auth::user()->id == $file->artist_id) {
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/' . $file->file_path));
    }
}
```

It's bad practice to return just a string. When using [Laravel responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses), Laravel makes sure the headers and other requirements are set correctly to return the response to the browser.

Comment: return response()->file($fileGet); gives me this error:  http://i.imgur.com/n5w4XMD.png 

I'd also like to point out that file_path value looks like this "/uploads/artistUploads/2/2/c/Azoruk/1493355445_3Yf358A.png", for example.

Comment: Where is this uploads folder located?

Comment: It's in storage/app.

Comment: Ah, actually it turns out the problem is the first "/" in front of uploads. I've corrected this and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: I updated my answer, you should use the [`storage_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-storage-path) function to link to files in the `storage` folder. Not sure if the `/` is required after `app`, this should possibly be removed depending on if `$file->file_path` starts with an `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `download` instead of `get` on `Storage` facade.

```php
public function getFile($fileID) {
    $file = CommUploads::where('id', $fileID)->first();

    if (Auth::user()->id == $file->user_id || Auth::user()->id == $file->artist_id) {
        return Storage::download($file->file_path);
    }
}
```